# LLM in LLMChain ignores prompt

Tags: python, langchain, gpt4all

I'm getting an incorrect output from an LLMChain that uses a prompt that contains a system and human messages.  Can't figure out why.  I download the gpt4all-falcon-q4_0 model from [here](https://gpt4all.io/index.html) to my machine.

```py
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain, LLMChain
from langchain.llms import GPT4All

from langchain.prompts import (
    PromptTemplate,
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
    ChatPromptTemplate
)

import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"..")
from local_config import MODEL_PATH

llm = GPT4All(
        model=MODEL_PATH,
        )

system_template = """
You are a helpful assistant who generates comma separated lists.
A user will only pass a category and you should generate subcategories of that category in a comma-separated list.
ONLY return comma-separated values and nothing more!
"""

system_message = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
    system_template
)

human_template = '{category}'

human_message = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_template)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([system_message, human_message])

chain = LLMChain(llm = llm,
                 prompt=prompt,
                 verbose=True)

chain.run('Machine Learning')
```

Instead of getting a string of comma-separated values, I get the following output:

```
Engineer\nSure, I can help you with that. Please provide the category for which you want to generate subcategories.
```

For reference, it does work if I just use a simpler template for the prompt:

```
template = """
Return all the subcategories of the following category
{category}
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["category"],
                        template = template)

chain = LLMChain(llm = llm,
                 prompt=prompt,
                 verbose=True)

chain.run('Machine Learning')
```

Output

````py
'Here\'s a Python function that takes in a list of categories and returns a list of all the subcategories of each category:\n```python\ndef get_subcategories(categories):\n    subcategories = []\n    for category in categories:\n        subcategories.append(category)\n    return subcategories\n```\nTo use this function, you can pass it a list of categories as an argument, like this:\n```python\ncategories = [\n    "Machine Learning",\n    "Deep Learning",\n    "Computer Vision",\n    "Natural Language Processing",\n    "Artificial Intelligence",\n    "Robotics",\n    "Game Development",\n    "Data Science",\n    "Big Data",\n    "Cloud Computing",\n    "Blockchain",\n    "Internet of Things",\n    "Cybersecurity",\n    "Machine Learning",\n    "Deep Learning",\n    "Computer Vision",\n    "Natural Language Processing",\n    "Artificial Intelligence",\n    "Robotics",\n    "Game Development",\n    "Data Science",\n    "Big Data",\n    "Cloud Computing",\n    "Blockchain",\n    "Internet of Things",\n    "Cybersecurity",\n]\n\nsubcategories = get_subcategories(categories)\nprint(subcategories)\n```\nThis'
````

Answer (score 1):

The code looks right. But the GPT4all-Falcon model needs well structured Prompts. Here are 2 things you look out for:

Your second phrase in your Prompt is probably a little to pompous. I think youve to split it up a little to make the instructions easier to understand.

Maybe change it from:

> """ You are a helpful assistant who generates comma separated lists. A
> user will only pass a category and you should generate subcategories
> of that category in a comma-separated list. ONLY return
> comma-separated values and nothing more! """

into:

> """ You are a helpful assistant who generates comma separated lists. A
> Human will only pass a category. Generate subcategories of that
> category in a comma-separated list. Return the comma-separated list!
> """

**Furthermore** something what most people forget is to place **\n** (next lines) on the right places in a prompt. Having zero \n in your string can make a huge difference with this model to having an \n after a phrase for example.
You can place \n either by pressing enter in your """String""" or write the string in one line like:

```
"""You are a helpful assistant who generates comma separated lists.\nA Human will only pass a category. Generate subcategories of that category in a comma-separated list.\nReturn the comma-separated list!\n"""


output:
* Data Science
* Artificial Intelligence
* Deep Learning
* Neural Networks
* Computer Vision
* Natural Language Processing
* Reinforcement Learning
* Game Theory
* Information Retrieval
* Knowledge Representation
......
```

good luck and happy prompting

Comment: Going in the right direction, but the output is separated by newlines, not commas.  Also, the output has some explanation before subcategories, whereas I need just the subcategories, hence the original prompt. Also, the question is - WHY is GPT4All more effective when the prompt is less 'pompous' as you wrote? The original prompt works with an OpenAI GPT3 model, so what makes GPT4All respond to these prompts differently. By the way, having the newlines (whether as '\n' or enter within """) doesn't seem to be making a difference, whether I have them with my original prompt or your updated one.

Comment: Generative AI is designed to generate new data. It can create diverse outputs from identical inputs, making it incredibly creative but somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: Gotcha, so your suggestion is something that you know from experience, but nobody really knows why it works fine on 1 LM but not on another.  Please write otherwise if I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: yes exactly thats what i mean

Comment: Thanks!  In that case, do you know which open-source LMs may perform better in this scenario?

Comment: No unfourtunately not. but maybe you google "deterministic llm" and read about that topic a bit